# Are there substances that can effectively mined from asteroids that can be used for ion thrusters?

Tags: propulsion, mining

The most popular ion thruster design seems to use Xenon. Unfortunately, due to it's low boiling point Xenon isn't easily available in space.

Are there other materials from which ion thrusters could be build that we could mine from asteroids?

Comment: For broad definitions of "ion thrusters", many gases will work.

Comment: Mining asteroid may seem like easy going way, but you would surprise how dependent mankind extraction techniques are to water, oxygen, carbon, chlorine, fluorine, sulfur even on Earth. Direct extraction techniques without any additional chemical are in it's infancy and could apply only to few compounds.